# Combine shape in folder for on/off

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to organize some shapes into folders to turn on/off all the shape togheter?
Is it useful for the shape that you can punt at the top/bottom of a project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use groups in the legend:

[image]

Please have a read though the [manual](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/html/en/docs/user_manual/index.html#qgis-manual-index-reference) if you are new to QGIS as this kind of thing is covered in there.

Comment: that's it! I have read the manual but it seems that I can reply the reading. Sorry for the easy question and thanks to solve it